# Can't get over Foreign Key Constraint on INSERT/DELETE in EF6 CF

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

Serious problem - I can not pass it.

I have two models.

```
class letter
{
public Guid id {get;set;}
public String subject  {get;set;}
}

class sended_letter
{
public Guid id {get;set;}
public Guid letterID{get;set;}
public DateTime sended{get;set;}
}
```

How should I setup these models, to achieve next things:

1. One-to-zero relation (rule by BL)
2. **sended_letter** are free to delete
3. **letter** on delete will delete related sended_letter. If it's impossible - then don't need
4. **sended_letter** always link to **letter** with **letterID**
5. Don't change **letter** entity. Letter doesn't know nothing about **sended_letter**

I can't get it done.

EF CF always create Foreign Key Constraint on **sended_letter** - and I can not delete **sended_letter** records.

WHY?!?!?!?!?!

I can drop FK CONSTRAINT, but it's not right.

I've tried use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<letter_sended>().HasRequired(x => x.letter).WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

but it's no go.

What should I do?!

Comment: imho, you are not in a WithRequired paradigm (and certainly not (WithRequiredPrincipal)[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679449%28v=vs.113%29.aspx]). Can you send multiple time the same letter, if yes WithMany(). Otherwise why don't you just add a sended property to the letter class ?

Comment: There is one sended record for one letter. And I want to keep it in separate table

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, I would go with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<letter_sended>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.letter)
            .WithOptional(x => x.letter_sended)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx